# System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Argument is out of range. error in a shortest path algorithm

Tags: c#, shortest-path

I am trying to solve a problem. This program contains all the edge in a graph. The shortest path from source to destination is to find out. I have function named dotest as below.

```
 public void dotest()
    {
        List<edge> tlist;
        Int32  x;
        setall();
        Int32 ind;
        foreach (edge e1 in alltest)
        {
            tlist = new List<edge>(alledge);

            ind = 0;
            foreach (edge e2 in tlist)
            {
                if (e2.s == e1.s && e2.d == e1.d)
                {
                    break;
                }
                ind++;


            }
            tlist.RemoveAt(ind);



            x=shortpath(tlist, start, destination);
            if (x != -1)
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", x);
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Infinity");

        }


    }
```

Describing the above code. The code already contains list of alledge(all the edge or path). I have got series of input that contains list of edge to cut off and I have to find the shortest path of the new updated edge list. I compiled my test case and some of test case worked. But for some test case it have error message as.

> Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Argument is out of range.
>   Parameter name: index
>   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ch_2_3_27.Solution+edge].RemoveAt (Int32 index) [0x00000] in :0 
>   at ch_2_3_27.Solution.dotest () [0x00000] in :0 
>   at ch_2_3_27.Solution.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in :0 
>   [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Argument is out of range.
>   Parameter name: index
>   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ch_2_3_27.Solution+edge].RemoveAt (Int32 index) [0x00000] in :0 
>   at ch_2_3_27.Solution.dotest () [0x00000] in :0 
>   at ch_2_3_27.Solution.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in :0

I really cannot locate out error and I think all other parts works fine. Anybody can help??

And Edge(edge) above is a struct with members s,d,w(source, destination, weight all Int 32)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is pretty clear actually. You are trying to remove an item from `tlist` at a certain index. However, that index does not have a value.

If I were to guess, I would say that this only happens whenever nothing in your `tlist` matches if `(e2.s == e1.s && e2.d == e1.d)`, so you end up with a +1 over the actual index of the `tlist` array.

To elaborate further, let's assume for simplicity that `tlist` has 1 item, then the index to use that item will be 0. If your if does not work, then you will set `ind++`, thus setting `ind` to 1. When you try to remove from the index at 1, then you get your error because there is only an object in the 0 index, and nothing in the 1 index

I would change the code to something more like this

```
        ind = -1;
        foreach (edge e2 in tlist)
        {
            ind++;
            if (e2.s == e1.s && e2.d == e1.d)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        if(ind != -1)
            tlist.RemoveAt(ind);
```

I would say to just do the RemoveAt inside of the if, however, that will result in a modified collection exception, so I believe this is the best solution.

Comment: But in the above code I found the certain index on searching from tlist. How come it doesnot have value?

Comment: @ErBnAcharya I updated the answer with extra elaboration and what will fix the code.

Comment: @ErBnAcharya That is your prerogative, but the way stack overflow works is that you ask a question (in this case, why you were getting the error), and we answer it. So, I answered correctly as to why you are getting an index out of range error. If you have another question beyond that, you should open up a new question. But, that is just how I have seen things run just about every time...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a new list of edge types and adding ones you want to remove in your calculations.  Then once complete - iterate over your "delete" list and remove them from the base list.  Also make sure you have IComparable so you can compare the objects and remove the correct one.